# How should I use a function in a model in React

Tags: reactjs

I have a user, I would like to make a helper function in model to see if the user is Admin, like that:

```
export class User {
    email;
    password;
    profile;

    constructor(email, password, profile) {
        this.email = email;
        this.password = password;
        this.profile = profile;
    }

    isAdmin() {
        return this.profile && this.profile.name === "ADMIN"
    }
}
```

and calling:

```
<BrowserRouter>
    <div>
        <Switch>
           {(user.isAdmin()) && <Redirect to={`/route`}/>}
        </Switch>
    </div>
</BrowserRouter>
```

But I get:

```
TypeError: user.isAdmin is not a function
```

How should I do it ? I use Redux

Comment: Was `user` created with `new`?

Comment: `user` come from jwt token. So I don't think so

Comment: let me double check it

Comment: If it was serialized from JSON then it does not have any prototype methods attached. You need to do some "extra work" to add in the prototype methods or use `new User(...)` to get a `isAdmin` function on the object.

Comment: Yep, I think it comes from local storage JSON string